# Telegram bot - can't use getUpdates method while webhook is active

Tags: python, chatbot, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

When I'm starting a bot after 10 minutes - 2 hours appears exception: `can't use getUpdates method while webhook is active`.

I already tried to delete webhook like that: [https://api.telegram.org/bot{token}/deleteWebhook](https://api.telegram.org/bot%7Btoken%7D/deleteWebhook), but it did not help.

Also, I noticed that after an exception was raised, bot replies to any message with a sticker.
[image: here is screenshot]

Here is the part of main file of the bot (The whole project you can see on my GitHub - https://github.com/MartsinovichDanya/Task_manager_telegram)

```py
    from telegram.ext import Updater, MessageHandler, Filters, CommandHandler
    from telegram import ReplyKeyboardRemove
    # ...
    updater = Updater(TOKEN)
    
    dp = updater.dispatcher
    
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
    
    
    # Клавиатура Босса
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.regex('Добавить задачу в проект'), write_proj_add_task))
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.regex('Удалить задачу из проекта'), write_proj_delete_task))
    
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.regex('Проекты'), project_options))
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.regex('Задачи'), task_options))
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.regex('Сотрудники'), employee_options))
    
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.regex('Добавить проект'), write_add_project))
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.regex('Удалить проект'), write_delete_project))
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.regex('Просмотр проектов'), select_project))
    
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.regex('Добавить задачу'), write_add_task))
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.regex('Удалить задачу'), write_delete_task))
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.regex('Просмотр задач'), task_preview))
    
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.regex('Добавить сотрудника'), write_add_employee))
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.regex('Удалить сотрудника'), write_delete_employee))
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.regex('Просмотр сотрудников'), select_employee))
    
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.regex('Главное меню'), start))
    
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.regex('Отчёты по Проектам'), project_report))
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.regex('Отчёты по Задачам'), task_report))
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.regex('Отчёты по Сотрудникам'), employee_report))
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.regex('Отчёты'), report))
    
    
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.regex('Назад'), back_to_report))
    
    
    # Клавиатура сотрудника
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.regex('Просмотр моих задач'), employee_task_preview))
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.regex('Выполнено'), select_done_task))
    
    # Создаём и удаляем тестовый обработчик текстовых сообщений (команд)
    projects_list = []
    employee_list = []
    
    em = EmployeeModel(db.get_connection())
    for e in em.get_all():
        employee_list.append(e[1])
    
    pm = ProjectModel(db.get_connection())
    for p in pm.get_all():
        projects_list.append(p[1])
    
    # Создаём обработчик текстовых сообщений типа Filters.text
    text_handler = MessageHandler(Filters.text, global_function)
    # Регистрируем обработчик в диспетчере.
    dp.add_handler(text_handler)
    
    # Запускаем цикл приема и обработки сообщений
    updater.start_polling()
    
    # Отправляем http запрос
    url = 'https://api.telegram.org/<bot_name_here>:<bot_token_here>/deleteWebhook'
    req = requests.get(url)
    print(req.status_code)
    
    # Ждём завершения приложения при нажатии клавиш Ctrl+C
    updater.idle()
```

If somebody knows how to solve that problem, please help me!

Comment: You just posted the bot secret token. Nobody must see it. Go to @BotFather and change it with the command /revoke. Never ever post a token again :)

Edit: and do not include the token in a GitHub repo

Answer (score 1):

You posted your TOKEN publicly and anybody can run your bot without your permission. And also reply with sticker or anything else.

Polling mode (with getUpdates) can be running only once at the same time and only if Webhooks are not set. And looks like someone repeatedly sets a webhook after some time (`10 minutes - 2 hours`).

To avoid that - delete [this file (`token`)](https://github.com/MartsinovichDanya/Task_manager_telegram/blob/master/token) from GitHub and remove everywhere from code. Use [environment variables](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ) instead.
And put `token` file to [`.gitignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) file.

After that revoke token of your bot using [@BotFather](https://t.me/BotFather) and update it everywhere you are using it.

Comment: This should be added as a comment, not a answer!

Comment: @0stone0 why? Her problem is that somebody else uses bot and setting webhook. Plus sending stickers as response. If she will fix that - problem will be solved.

Comment: Ahh, I'm sorry, didn't see that the token is probably getting abused by somebody else, maybe you could clarify that each token can only be used once?

Comment: @0stone0 added more explanation.